# Node app can't connect to database after setting up with nginx, phpmyadmin, and mysql on Ubuntu16

Tags: mysql, node.js, nginx, server, digital-ocean

I've successfully set up an node app with nginx reverse proxy, mysql and phpmyadmin. There's no problem access the database using phpmyadmin or access the website.

The error message I get when try to login:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED my-ip-address:3306
```

Is this an issue with mysql connection? I've already checked the code with mysql connection and can't figure out what's wrong.

```
  var connection = require("mysql").createPool({
    host: "my-ip-address",
    user: "root",
    password: "my-password",
    database: "database-name",
    dateStrings: true,
    charset: "utf8mb4"
  });
```

The /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name "my ip address";

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8010/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /phpmyadmin {
      root /var/www/html;
      index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

      location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME 
        $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

      }

    location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
        root /usr/share/;
      }
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock; 
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
         }
}
```

Comment: What's he output of `netstat -nltp`?

Comment: @Oliver I got these: Active Internet connections (only servers)tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9081/mysqld

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to connect to the database via the external IP address (`my-ip-address`) but the database is only listening on the local loopback interface (127.0.0.1 or localhost).

Try changing your host in the node app to `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`.

Important: do not make the DB listen on all ports (e.g. bind to address `0.0.0.0`) without first securing access via e.g. a firewall.

Comment: Hi I wonder if you can help me with this issue that came after setting the host in my node app. This is the server error log: [error] 18411#18411: *6443 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: (client ip), server:(my server ip address), request: "GET /sign-up-confirmed?access=2e1a9267b7a1188556b2013b33 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http:// 127.0.0.1:8010/sign-up-confirmed?access=2e1a9267b7a1188556b2013b33", host: "my server ip address".

Comment: `upstream prematurely closed connection` means your node app didn't respond to the request, check in the logs of the app to find out what's going on.